# extending FragmentActivity makes the backbutton lead to the latest new Activity

Tags: java, android, back-button, android-fragmentactivity

if this has already been asked and answered, sorry, but havent found it. 
Im new at android.

At the base of my application I have a class that extends Activity. It contains three buttons
whereof two lead to new classes that also extend activity. In these cases the physical back button leads back to the three buttons, which is what I want. 
In the third case the button leads to a class that extends FragmentActivity. Here pressing the physical backbutton exits the program instead. The class seems to need to extend FragmentActivity instead of activity, since it has an array of buttons, which display Dialogs when pressed, and these seem to need to be contained in a class that extends FragmentActivity!

Do I need to override the back button or is there something obvious Im missing?

This is the call to show the Dialog:

```
   public void showInfoVeryLight(View view){
        VeryLightDialogFragment vldf = new VeryLightDialogFragment();
        vldf.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"very light");
    }
```

This is VeryLightDialogFragment class:

```
public class VeryLightDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message_veryLight)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   }
               });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!:)

Comment: Is it the back button at the fragmentdialog or the fragment activity that exits?

Comment: At the Fragment Activity, but as I wrote below, the problem has disappeared now. I dont know why. thx for answering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really weird, but I worked with this problem off and on for a week, and as soon as I posted the question I did a testrun and the problem disappeared!

Right now the offending class that earlier lead out of the application instead leads back to the three buttons, and yet it extends FragmentActivity. So I guess this makes my question void - if I ever figure out what the h* happened Ill come post. :) :P